# wpf/mvvm - How to make a ComboBox that sets a specific value from selected item in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know how to use the bindings of the ComboBox, but how could I set the value for, say a string variable

```
public class Example
{
public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Using a ComboBox that has selectable items displayed as `[=, >, >=, <, <=]` in it and then convert them to the appropriate string `equals, greaterthan...` For example if a user selects `=` in the ComboBox then in the `public string Type { get; set; }` the value gets set as `equals` for it.

Im not sure how could I do this. Write code behind that looks for the selected item with IF's and sets the needed string? I really don't know and can't find any simillar examples. Any help would be nice, and I'm also making this in WPF/MVVM Light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for code behind for something like this.
Here's an approach using a dictionary:

```
public class Example
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> TypeItems { get; }
      = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
          // key part is "business" data
          // value part is for display only
          ["equals"] = "=",
          ["greaterthan"] = ">",
          ["greaterthanorequals"] = ">=",
          ["lesserthan"] = "<",
          ["lesserthanorequals"] = "<=",
      };

    public string SelectedType { get; set; }
}
```

On the XAML side of things:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding TypeItems}
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="Key"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Comment: Hm, would this work both ways if i need to return the previously selected item? @Seb

Comment: After Adding it to my code and fixing some issues ( I edited the code ) it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. To answer your question, yes, it can work both ways,just use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

The list of things you bind to can be any kind of object. Your ViewModel can look like this:

```
class Choice
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Choice> ComboBoxChoices { get; set; }

    public Choice SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ComboBoxChoices = new ObservableCollection<Choice>();
        ComboBoxChoices.Add(new Choice() { Symbol = "=", Description = "equals" });
        ComboBoxChoices.Add(new Choice() { Symbol = ">", Description = "greater than" });

        SelectedItem = ComboBoxChoices[0];
    }
}
```

And your XAML can look like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxChoices}" DisplayMemberPath="Symbol" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

When the ComboBox selection changes you can find the description you are looking for using this:

```
mainViewModel.SelectedItem.Description
```